# Cancan : how to exclude in ability?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using cancan to build comprehensive permissions system for my app. I need to be able to "exclude" some specific records even if there is a :read or :manage permissions set on the model e.g.

```
can :read , User
```

But I need to exclude specific ids ... something like:

```
can :read, User except when id in (1,2,3,.... list_of_excluded_ids)
```

I tried to make this work by building a list_of_excluded_ids like following:

```
all_ids = User.all
excluded_ids = Excluded.all (This model stores excluded ids)
permitted_id = all_ids - excluded_ids
```

Then with this list I iterate through setting permission for each id

```
permitted_ids.each do |permitted_id|
can :read, User, :id => permitted_id
end
```

This method works when the list of all ids is small. When list is large it carshes mysql  with memory errors,  as it produces a very long sql query using OR like this:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE ((`users`.`id` = 271) OR ((`users`.`id` = 270) OR ((`users`.`id` = 269) OR ((`users`.`id` = 268) OR ((`users`.`id` = 267) OR ((`users`.`id` = 266) OR ((`users`.`id` = 265) OR ((`users`.`id` = 264) OR ((`users`.`id` = 263) OR .....))))))
```

The query above is just for example as I cannot post the whole query here. This query becomes so large that it makes mysql crash. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a scope to the ability:

```
can :read, User, User.where(id => permitted_ids) do |u|
  permitted_ids.include? u.id
end
```

Assuming `permitted_ids` is an array, this will use a SQL "IN" clause to scope your users for index actions. For show actions, CanCan will use the block, passing in the user being accessed. Note the block and the scope do the same thing. This seems silly, but CanCan requires that you provide a block when using a scope that it will use for the show action.